# On-line banking account with Maestro (or some other debit card)

Tags: online-banking, croatia

I need an account outside of Croatia where I live in, to link it with PayPal to be able to gather income generated by it.  I would like to avoid USA banks, and in fact, I would like to find the general principal on how to fund such banks or service providers.

I found some information here:

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=587472

Question could be rewriten as: how can I open US non-resident bank account from Croatia, prefferably on-line?

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to open a bank account in a neighboring country to Croatia. Paypal has network in 190 countries. An [Italian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banking_in_Italy) bank may have more favorable currency exchange fees from the Euro to the Kuna.

https://www.paypal.com/worldwide/

A possible alternative if you already have a Paypal account is to apply for a [Paypal debit card](https://personal.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/debit_card). Then you can withdraw funds directly from your Paypal account without needing a bank to transfer the funds to first. The Paypal Debit card is backed by Mastercard.

Comment: Paypal debit card - only for US citizens.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest way will be to physically go to Austria, walk into any major bank in a major city with your passport and open an account. Although to withdraw to that account from Paypal your address on the Paypal account also will need to be in Austria, and Paypal at any time may ask you to verify that address, for example with an utility bill.

So you would need to have a good friend in Austria that would let you use his address as the contact address for both the bank account and Paypal and possibly add you as a payer of his utility bill. Be prepared for that, because even though Paypal will happily allow you to open an account without proof of address, at the moment you will start receiving substantial incoming transfers to you Paypal account, will ask for a document (for example utility bill) verifying your address and will freeze your account with your money until you present such document.

Using your Croatian address might work for the Austrian bank, but will NOT work for Paypal, because then it'll not give you an option to withdraw to an Austrian bank.